# Как скачать файл с Web с помощью Win API?

Tags: winapi, windows, c++

Как скачать файл с Web с помощью Win API?

Answer (score 2):

Для этого подходит Winet API:

```
BYTE buffer[TOTAL];
DWORD total = 0, read = 0;

while (InternetReadFile(from, buffer + total, TOTAL - total, &read) != FALSE) {
    // Проверить объем скачанных данных
    // Что-нибудь сделать с данными
}
```

Подробнее: [введение в WinInet](http://www.rsdn.ru/article/inet/wininet.xml).

Comment: Вопрос был о Win API, а не об обертках.

Comment: В широком смысле слова WinINet входит в Windows API. Обычно противопоставляют MFC или .NET и "голый" API.

Answer (score -1):

Сокеты + протоколы ftp и http

Comment: Какой вопрос -- такой ответ. Лаконично. @Sawich Только я думал, что сессии уже кончились. Или это для второго семестра?